# How can I refuel a Cybran dragonfly?

Tags: supreme-commander

I can't seem to be able to refuel the Cybran unit carrier, the dragonfly. It doesn't have the "dock to refuel and repair" order in its menu, like other air units do; directing it to an airfield, cruiser or aircraft carrier causes them to pointlessly circle around.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it appears that letting them rest a for while on the ground refuels them automatically.

Comment: Any other ways?

Comment: I don't know... The dragonfly is also unique in that it can be repaired by an engineer, unlike other air units. It looks like it's a small discrepancy in game design.

Comment: on FAF all of them can be repaired. but yeah there is no refueling for cybran. it's the guerrilla tactics faction. they don't have time to think about logistics. but yeah landing them will do the trick. this works for all air units of all races.